# Is there any good idea about how to tuning the web application's performance?

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, nginx

Hi~ we are working on a small project which we want it to be public on line. Now our project runs well in the local, However when we just hoop it on line, the respond speed is so slow. we are all new to web development area, so Please provide some tips or suggestions .Thank you.

We use php, mysql as database and nginx as server.

Any advice is more than welcome. Thank you again.

Comment: more infrastructure details are needed. What's the difference between the local and public setups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few tips:

**Code Profiling**

Use [xdebug's profiling option](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). This will give you insight into areas of your code that may need optimization.

**SQL Profiling**

Most of my projects use PostgreSQL, so I haven't actually used this myself, but here's some documentation on [profiling your MySQL queries](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/using-new-query-profiler.html). Again, it'll give you insight into areas of your SQL scripts that could use some optimization.

**Investigate Cache Options**

If you have a lot of database queries on your pages or a lot of PHP logic in your pages, it can be expensive to generate. There are a few different methods of cacheing and, while each method helps to solve load times, each aims to solve different specialized problems:

- [File based cache](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/output-caching-for-beginners/) (article that explains the concept fairly well)
- [APC cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.apc.php)
- [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php)
- [MySQL query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html)

These would be the first steps that I'd take in optimizing one of my projects.

**Edit:**

TVK's suggestion is also good for nailing down client side performance issues.

Comment: Thank you. I will dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only occurring when you have to transfer the actual data, this addon by Google will be great for finding things to improve: http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

It will perform a bunch of algorithms to find things to optimise in your HTML as well as CSS and JavaScript.